# Html Block-quote Styling and placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made the html block-quote the way i wanted to look using Css before and after and mostly happy with look except i can't seem to figure out how to align the quote to go right in front of the sentence and right after like a regular quote, now it is at the top of the text and bottom of the text. I used some padding and margin but not very dynamic and responsive, like when adding or remove the amount of text the position of the quote is changing and looking bad on mobile. How can i achive this

**Current :** (ignore the style of the quote, just want to position )

[image]

**I want to the quote to look like this :**(ignore the style of the quote, just want to position )

[image]

My Current Code:

```css
blockquote {
    line-height: 1.5em;

}

blockquote:before {
    content: open-quote;
}

blockquote:after {
    content: close-quote;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: #2793c6;
    font-size: 64px;
    top: 0.3em;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: 4.92px;
}

blockquote p{
    font-size: 28px !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-stretch: normal !important;
    letter-spacing: normal !important;
    color: #002856 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:10%">
        <blockquote>
            <p>

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nihil, illum cum. Delectus natus numquam nihil
                animi a veniam assumenda, ducimus eaque impedit dolor, cum nemo similique. Tempora voluptate enim velit.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nihil, illum cum. Delectus natus numquam nihil
                animi a veniam assumenda, ducimus eaque impedit dolor, cum nemo similique. Tempora voluptate enim velit.
            </p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[block quote example](https://jsfiddle.net/wb84q6nv/)

You can do this with positioning.
The open-quote can be absolutely positioned before the start of your blockquote element. the ending one can be a span places at the end of your paragraph. and can move it around using position:relative;

```
.open-quote {
  position:absolute;
  top:8px;
  left:-20px;
  font-size:36pt;
  color:blue;
}
.close-quote {
  font-size:36pt;
  position:relative;
  top:13px;
  color:blue;
}

.open-quote:after {
  content: open-quote;
}

.close-quote:after {
  content: close-quote;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10%">
<blockquote>
<span class="open-quote"></span>
    <p>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nihil, illum cum. Delectus natus numquam nihil
        animi a veniam assumenda, ducimus eaque impedit dolor, cum nemo similique. Tempora voluptate enim velit.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nihil, illum cum. Delectus natus numquam nihil
        animi a veniam assumenda, ducimus eaque impedit dolor, cum nemo similique. Tempora voluptate enim velit.<span class="close-quote"></span>
    </p>
</blockquote>
</div>
```